# Use Azure DevOps REST API to Delete organizations / accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is it possible to Delete an organization / account within Azure DevOps using the REST API? You can delete other entities, but the documentation doesn't show a DELETE command for Accounts / Organizations.

Is this something that's possible? Thanks!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/account/accounts?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: What scenario are you envisioning where you'd have enough accounts to need to automate the process of deleting them?

Comment: @DanielMann I have an classroom lab environment where I need to automate the deletion of Azure DevOps organizations associated with an Azure Subscription that's reused across multiple different lab environment instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you no longer need your organization in Azure DevOps, you can delete it. If you change your mind within 30 days, you can recover your organization. After 30 days, your organization and data are permanently deleted.

It's **not able to do this through Rest API** at present. You have to do this in web portal.

There are also some limitation to directly call rest api to delete organization. For example you must first meet the prerequisites:

> If your organization uses an Azure subscription to bill purchases, you
>   must first remove billing from your organization in the Azure portal
>   before you can delete your organization in Azure DevOps.

In the resulting dialog box, enter the name of the organization, and select Delete.

[image]

More details please take a look at this official tutorial: [Delete your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/delete-your-organization?view=azure-devops)